# Split cell with specific formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to find and split an input in cell A2, and it needs to output in a specific format up to 3 digits after the second period and not outputting anything after if it finds a 3rd period.

I'm currently using:

```
=IF(A2="","",TEXT(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(".",A2,1)-1),"00000")&"."&TEXT(MID(A2,SEARCH(".",A2)+1,SEARCH(".",A2,SEARCH(".",A2)+1)-SEARCH(".",A2)-1),"000000")&"."&TEXT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(".",A2,SEARCH(".",A2)+1)),"000"))
```

however this pulls ALL data after the 2nd period. As you can see from the formula I need the first numbers to output in 5 digits, the next numbers after the first period output in 6 digits, and the ones after the 2nd should output in 3 digits

In short the output SHOULD look like 00000.000000.000 even if someone puts 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0; HOWEVER, it's currently capturing everything after the 2nd period so in reality it actually looks like 00000.000000.0.0.0.0.0.0

Is there anything I can add to make it cut off the output once it reaches a third period? I would use a regular split function, but when people are inputting data sometimes they put 0000.000000.000.0.0.0.0.0 sometimes they put 00000.000000.000.0.0.0.0 sometimes they put 0000.000000.000. many different combinations, but the separation point is always the period and the end result always needs to be 5digits.6digits.3digits

Let me know if I need to clarify any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following would give you what you need.

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1),"00000")&"."&TEXT(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,FIND(".",A2,FIND(".",A2)+1)-FIND(".",A2)-1),"000000")&"."&TEXT(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2,FIND(".",A2)+1)+1,3),"000")
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you! Side question - Assuming they do add something after that last dot, how would I go about pulling that information separately until the next dot? Example: they type
1234.12.123.123456 which of course your function will convert it to 01234.00012.123 as intended, but if I need that 123456 in a separate cell how would I go about doing that (only if they add it)

Comment: Sorry @CLR I editted my comment. Please assist if you can :)

Comment: Looks like =IF(LEN(A2) < 17, "", TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",REPT(" ",99)),99))) will work for me for my second question.

Comment: That does work, it's certainly an interesting way of doing it too. If you want to 'Find' the fourth section without risking mistakes - try the following: `=IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",""))>=3,MID(A2,FIND(".",A2,FIND(".",A2,FIND(".",A2)+1)+1)+1,99),"")`

Comment: This method checks that there are at least 3 `.` present and then finds the 3rd and presents the next 99 characters after that.

Comment: Thanks! That works pretty well as well as a safeguard. Appreciate it. I'll use that instead.